# I cannot get my .jar file to run but it can run within intellij when running the main class

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

`> WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @6df5feea'

> Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw
> Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
> at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:283)
> at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:253)
> at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:263)
> at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:290)
> at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:162)
> at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:651)
> at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:671)
> at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
> at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:95)
> at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
> 1 more
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
> at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:275)
> at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:290)
> at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:162)
> at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:651)
> at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:671)
> at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
> `

This is what shows up when i try to run it within the terminal. I have re-added the javafx files and reinstalled them. What can i do now?

Comment: You have incorrectly assembled a runtime image (a JavaFX app that runs outside of an IDE), making JavaFX native components inaccessible.  Follow the getting started instructions at [openfjx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/)., specifically the section on runtime images.  Also see the packaging section of the [javafx tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info).  You could check the [hundred duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Graphics+Device+initialization+failed+%5Bjavafx%5D).

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).